# How to click on a d3 charts using selenium

Tags: selenium, canvas, d3.js

I have a `d3` type chart to automate.

I tried using action class but it is not getting clicked.

code I used is :

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = ".//*[@class='someid]")]
public IWebElement chart{ get; set; }

Actions act = new Actions(_driver);

act.MoveToElement(chart,155, 215).Click().Build().Perform();
```

[image]

in the above chart all the color is clickable and it will take to another page,by using selenium i am not able to differentiate each color and click on them

not able to differentiate using different xpath.

attached html of the chart.
[image]
can anyone help me on this ,Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried WebElement's `click()`?

Comment: Try once `chart.Click()`...and let me know..

Comment: You should be ale to use some api of this implementation to ease your work.